# Initialized tuple element becoming NoneType

Tags: python, pygame, tuples, nonetype

I init a tuple here

```
players = [Player("Local", (0,0), 20)]
```

and whenever I try to access any of the player's classes members from that element I get a NoneType object has no attribute 'model' error:

```
players[0].model.pos = mousepos
```

I don't understand why I can't use that element because I am initializing that element as type 'Player'

Thanks in advance

Edit: keep in mind that I make no modifications to players or any of it's elements in between those 2 snippets

Edit2: Class definitions

```
class Circle():
    pos = (0,0)
    radius = 0.0

class Player():
    name = ""
    model = Circle()
    def __new__(self, Name = "", pos = (0,0), radius = 0):
        name = Name
        model = Circle()
        model.pos = pos
        model.radius = radius
```

Comment: Can you show us your `Player` class definition

Comment: I suspect this is a scope issue.

Comment: Show us a bit more code, please - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve We don't have enough to go on with what you've shown us.

Comment: `players` is a list, not a tuple. Tuples are delimited with `()`, `[]` makes lists.

Comment: It doesn't matter if players is a list or a tuple, I don't think it's a scope issue. Both lines aren't in any function. The only thing between the two is a while loop which the second snippet is nested in

Comment: Why are you using `__new__` instead of `__init__`? I suspect that's the problem.

Comment: That was the issue. Fixed

Comment: `__new__` is required to create and return the new object. Since it doesn't have a `return` statement, it returns `None`.

Comment: @CowNation: If that was the problem, I foresee further problems ahead when you make more `Player`s.

Comment: Who knew @quamrana was a genie?!

Comment: @CowNation You're using classes wrong. All your members are class members, not instance members. In python, you set instance variables inside `__init__` by assigning to the parameter `self`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `__init__` instead of `__new__`

Here is an example for `__init__` and `__new__`:

```
class newStyleClass(object): 
    # In Python2, we need to specify the object as the base.
    # In Python3 it's default.

    def __new__(cls):
        print("__new__ is called")
        return super(newStyleClass, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        print("__init__ is called")
        print("self is: ", self)

newStyleClass()
```

Code achieved from https://www.jianshu.com/p/14b8ebf93b73
(Chinese website)